# what are mandatory elements in OpenAPI spec

Tags: openapi, apigee

What are the mandatory elements of OpenAPI spec? 
my assumption is OpenAPI, Info and Path, Is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum required fields in OpenAPI definitions are:

- OpenAPI version identifier, such as `openapi: 3.1.0` or `swagger: '2.0'`
- `info.title`
- `info.version`
- For OpenAPI 3.1:

  - One of: `paths`, `components`, `webhooks`. These sections can be empty, e.g. `paths: {}`.
- For OpenAPI 3.0.x and 2.0:

  - `paths` – can be empty, i.e. `paths: {}`

Sample minimal definition:

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: My API
  version: 1.0.0
paths: {}
```

Technically `info.title` and `info.version` can also be [empty strings](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1625) (such as `title: ''`), although this wouldn't make sense in practice.